# What would be the best way to Post relational Data to a complex data model using Angular and Net Core?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

Trying to figure out the best way to POST relational data, am also wondering if the way I'm handling the backend is the best way.

Is there a way to POST in one singular step? Or should I make a service or a pipe to call what's been written in the first table and then post relative data to the other? That would be my best bet right now but it sounds like over-thinking and over-doing at the moment to me.

I have tried many ways to post but I can't seem to grasp what's happenning, the "relative" db stays empty although I have Icollection in ef core. (see code).

Here is the backend model in netcore 2.2 :

```
MainList {

        public Guid JdbTdcMainListId { get; set; }
        public string JTSubject { get; set; }
        public string JTDescription { get; set; }
        public bool JTImportant { get; set; }
        public bool JTPertinentToReporting { get; set; }
        public string JTCreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string JTLastEditBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime JTEntryCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime JTEntryModified { get; set; }

        public Guid JTCatId { get; set; }
        public Guid JTSubCatId { get; set; }
        public Guid JTBatId { get; set; }
        public Guid JTReportId { get; set; }
        public Guid JTReturnId { get; set; }

        public JTCat JTCats { get; set; }
        public JTSubCat JTSubCats { get; set; }
        public JTRapport JTRapports { get; set; }
        public JTRetour JTRetours { get; set; }
        public JTBatphone JTBatphones { get; set; }
}
```

So this would be a main list to which I wish to document all the related data to the entries in the tables referenced at the bottom, Cat & SubCat are related to each other for a categorisation system., there's some reporting data and other things.

Here is how I setup the relationship with the MainList in JTCats :

```
JTCat {
     public Guid JTCatId { get; set; }
     public string JTCatNom { get; set; }
     public string JTCatDescription { get; set; }
     public bool JTCatHasTextTemplate { get; set; }
     public string JTCatTextTemplate { get; set; }
     public bool JTCatActive { get; set; }
     public ICollection<JTMainList> JTMainList { get; set; }
}
```

Using a repository pattern and automatically scaffolded controllers in vs studio 2017.

And then my angular model looks like this :

```
import { JdbTdcMainList } from './jdbTdcMainList.model';

export interface JTCat {
    jTCatId?: string;
    jTCatNom: string;
    jTCatDescription: string;
    jTCatHasGabarit: boolean;
    jTCatActif: boolean;
    jTMainList: JTMainList[];
}
```

Here is my angular template and component, could use some help formatting the validation :

```
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row">
    <form 
        [formGroup]="MainGroup"
        (ngSubmit)="send()"
        novalidate>
    <input type="hidden" readonly formControlName="Data1" id="Data1" class="form-control"/>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" readonly formControlName="Data2" id="Data2" class="form-control"/>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" readonly formControlName="Data3" id="Data3" class="form-control"/>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="hidden" readonly formControlName="Data4" id="Data4" class="form-control"/>
    <div formGroupName="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="23">
                    <select size="35" formControlName="ChildData1" id="ChildData1" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        <option value="06:00">06:00</option>
                        <option value="06:30">06:30</option>
                        etc.
                    </select> 
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <th>ChildData2 :</th>
                    <th>ChildData3  :</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="number" size="3" value="0" formControlName="ChildData2" id="ChildData2" class="form-control form-control-sm" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" size="3" value="0" formControlName="ChildData3" id="ChildData3" class="form-control" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>ChildData4</th>
                    <th>ChildData5<th>
                    etc..

        </table> 
    </div>     
</form>
</div>
<app-success-modal [modalHeaderText]="'Success message'" 
  [modalBodyText]="'Action completed successfully'" [okButtonText]="'OK'" 
  (redirectOnOK)="redirectToRapportList()">
</app-success-modal>
<app-error-modal [modalHeaderText]="'Error message'" 
  [modalBodyText]="errorMessage" [okButtonText]="'OK'">
</app-error-modal>
```

And here is the component, how do I validate and execute POST?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { RepositoryService } from 'src/app/shared/services/repository.service';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from 'src/app/shared/services/error-handler.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateRapport } from '../../_interfaces/jdbtdc/CreateRapport.model';
import { formGroupNameProvider } from '@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_name';
import { MainListRapportCreate } from 'src/app/_interfaces/jt/mainlistRapportCreate.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rapport-create',
    templateUrl: './rapport-create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./rapport-create.component.css'] 
})
export class RapportCreateComponent implements OnInit {
    public errorMessage: string = '';
    public createJdbRapportForm: FormGroup;
constructor(private repository: RepositoryService, private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService, private router: Router, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.createJdbRapportForm = this.fb.group({
        Data1:  ['ReportTitle'],
        Data2:  ['ReportDescription'],
        Data3:  ['Identity_Data_From_IIS'],
        Data4:  new Date(),
            child: this.fb.group({
                ChildData1: new Date(),
                ChildData2: ['0'],
                Etc. 
            })
    });
}
public send() {
    if (this.createJdbRapportForm['controls'].child['controls'].valid) {
        this.executeEntryCreation()

    }
}
private executeEntryCreation(createJdbRapportForm) {
    let EntryCreate: CreateRapport = {
        jdbTdcSujet: createJdbRapportForm.jdbTdcSujet,
        jdbTdcDescription: createJdbRapportForm.jdbTdcDescription,
        jdbTdcCreatedBy: createJdbRapportForm.jdbTdcCreatedBy,
        jdbTdcEntryCreated: createJdbRapportForm.jdbTdcEntryCreated
    child:
    jdbTdcRapportEntryDateTime: createJdbRapportForm.jdbTdcRapportEntryDateTime,
```

^^ Here is where I have no clue what to do to execute this. How do I merge the child with the main form before I execute POST?

But here is the interface I'm using :

```
export interface CreateRapport {
    Data1: string;
    Data2: string;
    Data3: string;
    Data4: string;
    etc.
        child: [{
            ChildData1: string;
            ChildData1: number;
            ChildData1: number;
            ChildData1: number;
            etc.
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a model like this in your FE code

```
const model: JTCat  = { 
    jTCatId: "some data";
    jTCatNom: "some data";
    jTCatDescription: "some data";
    jTCatHasGabarit: true;
    jTCatActif: true;
    jTMainList: [
        {
          // your data
        },
        {
           // your data
        }
    ];

}
```

Comment: I think shaping the model this way was the only missing piece of this puzzle. I started learning 3 months ago, thanks a lot for you help. Will come back as soon as I try.

Comment: I've edited my post with my angular code. How would I process from there?

Comment: can you provide me full source code on github or you can upload to https://stackblitz.com